# Return min value in group with lambda/linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, linq-to-objects

I need help creating a lambda expression to query the following list for retrieving the lowest priced item in each channel. Ie for this example item A, D and G

```
class Radio
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Channel { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

List<Radio> radios = new List<Radio>();
radios.Add(new Radio() { Name = "A", Channel = 1, Price = 10 });
radios.Add(new Radio() { Name = "B", Channel = 1, Price = 20 });
radios.Add(new Radio() { Name = "C", Channel = 1, Price = 30 });
radios.Add(new Radio() { Name = "D", Channel = 2, Price = 10 });
radios.Add(new Radio() { Name = "E", Channel = 2, Price = 20 });
radios.Add(new Radio() { Name = "F", Channel = 2, Price = 30 });
radios.Add(new Radio() { Name = "G", Channel = 3, Price = 10 });
radios.Add(new Radio() { Name = "H", Channel = 3, Price = 20 });
radios.Add(new Radio() { Name = "I", Channel = 3, Price = 30 });
```

Comment: great question. same with my problem that is wonferfully defined

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using Linq,

First Group  using [Enumerable.GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx)
Then Sort  using [Enumerable.OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx)
Then Take [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx) of each sorted items in group

```
    radios.GroupBy(x=> x.Channel).Select(x=>x.OrderBy(y=>y.Price)).Select(x=>x.First());
```

Answer (score 14):

You can also do this without doing an expensive sort on each group:

```
radios.GroupBy(x => x.Channel).Select(g =>
    g.Aggregate((r1, r2) => r1.Price < r2.Price ? r1 : r2));
```

The `Aggregate` iterates through each group once, keeping track of the cheapest radio it's found so far and replacing it if it finds a cheaper one.