# How do you display the SQL statement of a Linq-To-SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to retrieve the earliest DateTime value that has a specific date.
The Holder instance has already been retrieved from the data context (without prefetching), now I need to search through the IO EntitySet (that has not been fetched).

I'm doing this in a foreach loop for each holder so it takes a long time to retrieve the requested values. Indexing the table didn't help so I want to see the SQL statement in order to optimize the database.

This is the code that needs to be translated into SQL:

```
DateTime? entryDateTime = (from io in Holder.IOs
                           where  io.IOStatus == "Entry" &&
                                  io.IODateTime.HasValue &&
                                  io.IODateTime.Value.Date == date.Date
                                  select io.IODateTime).Min();
```

I **can't** use LinqPad because the linq statement doesn't directly quesry the DataContext, but the IOs EntitySet.

*Also, if anyone has an idea on how to rewrite the linq statement in order to speed up the retrievals, please let me know. I don't want to use LoadOptions as this would delay the app starting process.*

Comment: foreach loop for each holder? How many holders? This will load IOs one by one so for each holder you get a separate query

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644078/return-min-value-in-group-with-lambda-linq-query

Answer (score 2):

Grab the query, stop on it in in the debugger. YOu should be able to see it with a mouse over on the query object.

I think your problem is the Min. You get in SQL what you have in LINQ, and this is not what I would do in SQL.

I would gl with an order by and a Top 1 - which translates into First () in LINQ.

Comment: What query object are you referring to? I'll give your suggestion a try.

Comment: The one you can create. WIthout the Min() it is an IQUeryable you get back ;) Put that into a variable.

Comment: the `orderby` and `FirstOrDefault()` take the same execution time. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I also couldn't find the SQL statement in the linq object.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options. Use a profiler on your database.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx
or
[Where can I get the old, free version of Anjlab's SQL Profiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781910/where-can-i-get-the-old-free-version-of-anjlabs-sql-profiler)

Or coding: hack into the LINQ 2 SQL log: 
http://damieng.com/blog/2008/07/30/linq-to-sql-log-to-debug-window-file-memory-or-multiple-writers